# Best/suitable algorithm for project slot assignment problem?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I have a requirement where there are multiple projects available with corresponding schedule dates and schedule reviewing dates.

There will be N number of projects available and each project will have a schedule date as part of the deliverable process. The requirement is to assign each project to the earliest available project schedule review slot. Lets say a project is having a schedule date which is tomorrow, i need to find a available review date slot prior to the schedule date and assign the project based on priority level. Maximum I can assign a project to the earliest available slot is 7 days prior to the actual scheduling date of the project.
For example

| Project | Complexity | Schedule Date | schedule review slot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 15-02-2022 | 12-02-2022 09:00 - 10:00 |
| 2 | B | 15-02-2022 | 12-02-2022 11:00 - 12:00 |
| 3 | C | 15-02-2022 | 12-02-2022 12:00 - 01:00 |
| 4 | A | 16-02-2022 | 13-02-2022 09:00 - 10:00 |

My desired output

| Project | Complexity | Schedule Date | schedule review slot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 15-02-2022 | 12-02-2022 09:00 - 10:00 |
| 4 | A | 16-02-2022 | 12-02-2022 12:00 - 01:00 |
| 2 | B | 15-02-2022 | 12-02-2022 11:00 - 12:00 |
| 3 | C | 15-02-2022 | 13-02-2022 09:00 - 10:00 |

I am new to algorithm concepts. So could anyone please guide me in this

Comment: I do not really understand what your goal is. You really should add requirements for the review date assignment and add a question.

Comment: @JakobStark Thanks for your comment. I am new to the community so apologize for the mistakes. I have edited the post. Kindly let me know your inputs

Comment: That already is a lot better ;) However there are still a few points missing. I assume the complexities (A, B, and C) are the priorities of the projects. Is that correct? You want an ordering by priorities AND schedule times. Therefore you must specify, which is the more important one. If project X has a higher priority but later schedule date than project Y, should it be reviewed earlier or later than project Y?

Comment: @JakobStark Yes you are correct, Complexities are the priorities. And also regarding the projects X and Y, as per your comment, Project X should be reviewed earlier since it has higher priority than Project Y

Comment: Ok, then why is Project #2 scheduled before Project #4 in your example even though it has lower priority?

Comment: @JakobStark Made the changes. Its just that confusing to create the table for the first time

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:

1. Sort the projects into groups with equal complexity/priority, so that all projects with priority A are in the same group, all projects with priority B are in the same group and so on.
2. Sort the projects in each group by their schedule date, so that the projects with the earliest schedule date come first.
3. Sort the awailable review time slots by time, so that the earliest time slot comes first.

With this input you can go with the following algorithm:

1. Take the first (earliest) time slot. Let's call it `T`.
2. Take the first (earliest) project `P` from the sorted priority A list.
    **If** `P` is scheduled less than 7 days after `T`, assign it to `T`, remove `T` and `P` from their lists and go to step 1.
   **Else** try the same for the earliest project from the priority B and C lists. If none is scheduled less than 7 days after the `T`, leave the time slot `T` unassigned and move back to step 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, i have something to start with now. But do you have any idea is there any existing algorithm or similar  to tackle this problem. Just for the reference purpose

Comment: It seems like this algorithm could fail to assign everyone in order to prioritize the groups. For example, two total review slots, on days 1 and 3. Two projects total; priority B on day 2 and priority A on day 4. Priority A would get scheduled on day 1, and priority B would be unassigned, while you could have scheduled both. This may not be what OP intended, but it's not fully clear.